# Reading JSON file via JavaScript across different subdomain?

Tags: javascript, security, json, cross-domain

Is it possible (and if so, what's the most secure way) to read a JSON file from a subdomain such as somesubomain.maindomain.com in a JS script residing in maindomain.com, another.maindomain.com etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at how `document.domain` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.domain

Another solution would be make your json file a JavaScript file (jsonp-style) which calls a function so it can be embedded using a script tag which does not have same-origin restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Your not supposed to due to the same origin policy enforced on all browsers, but you can... Check out this explanation of cross domain ajax requests.

http://alexsexton.com/?p=154

JSONP is what I found to be the easiest to work with for this type of stuff.

Comment: JSONP is a useful technique, but it's not a loophole.  The response is really just JavaScript, and it requires server cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

I do this two ways:

1. Have your server make the call on behalf of your client. What I mean by that, is take the call you were going to make from the browser, and make it a web service on the server. Then have your client call your webservice, which will then make the call and return the response. This allows you to inspect what's being sent back and forth.
2. Use JSONP. Their server must be configured for this, and I'm not sure there is any added security..